# Django: "No module named context_processors" error after reboot

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-middleware

I have a Django site that works on my PC, and was working briefly on my server after loading it on. I noticed my server had Django 1.6 and I upgraded to 1.8.

After rebooting, none of the pages on my site load and I get the error:

> ImportError No module named context_processors

I read through the docs on Django and allauth. Django mentions that in 1.8 the context_processors moved and allauth says specific allauth tags are no longer needed in the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` of `settings.py`.

Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/

Allauth: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Anyone else run into this? Am I on the right track? Do I need to change something in settings? I can't really tell if it's a Django or allauth issue so not sure where to start.

Any help is appreciated!

Traceback:

```
Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'plant',
 'journal',
 'userimg',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/django/django_project/plant/views.py" in plant_main
  24.     return render(request, 'plant/plant_main.html', context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                 with context.bind_template(self):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
  17.             return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
  237.         processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  60.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/engine.py" in template_context_processors
  90.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/template/engine.py" in <genexpr>
  90.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/module_loading.py" in import_string
  26.     module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /plant/
Exception Value: No module named context_processors
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback for your error? That will be a more helpful starting point.

Comment: Just updated. Meant to do it the first time around. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you have anything set in your TEMPLATES setting for `context_processors`? From the look of it, you may have an app listed in there which doesn't actually contain any context processors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was that I had no TEMPLATES setting in settings.py as required after upgrading to Django 1.8. I'm not really clear why it was working on my PC using the Django server.

From the allauth docs, I pasted this into my settings file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Already defined Django-related contexts here

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And copied the contents of my old `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting into the DIRS definition for TEMPLATES. The final result looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Already defined Django-related contexts here

                # `allauth` needs this from django
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

According to the documentation for a recent allauth update, `context_processors` now need to be specified in the TEMPLATES setting and not `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Thanks to [Joey Wilhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971587/joey-wilhelm) for pointing me in the right direction on this.

Comment: Ah good. I was wondering if that might be the case. Django 1.8 introduced multiple database backends, so it uses new settings. You may want to check through the release notes to ensure there are no other major changes you need to update for. Also, two good commands you may want to run: `manage.py check` and `manage.py diffsettings`.

Comment: **I'm not really clear why it was working on my PC ...** Perhaps after you upgrade you don't have deleted the *.pyc files?.  Of course this is a question I'm not expecting answer. It's just for thinking about it ;)

Answer (score 59):

I encountered the same problem but I am upgrading from 1.9.1 to 1.10. I found there's a little difference in the settings.

This is the code from 1.9.1

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

This is code for 1.10

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

The line `django.core.context_processors.request` is not valid in 1.10. Remove it and the code works well.

Comment: I think you are supposed to change `django.core.context_processors` to `django.template.context_processors`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors). Just by removing the line as mark  suggests, would leave you without request in context. Thanks anyway, since you got me into right direction!

Comment: @Jeewes Yep, core has been changed to template, that was the issue for me, reading the docs everytime to keep you updated is crucial and sad lol

Comment: What does BASE_DIR refer to? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jason. here's definition of BASE_DIR.  BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: @Jeewes, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip: When a traceback doesn't provide you with the information you need to identify the exact line of code; It can be helpful to enable `DEBUG` mode, and open the page in the browser. There's this wonderful little `local_vars` element, where you can see local variable state when the traceback occurs. It can be super handy!

(In my case, it was related to changes within allauth)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to delete the following line in settings.py:

```
            'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
```

I rebooted the server and I didn't see that error again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is updated source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```