# ImportError: No module named context_processors

Tags: python, django

I am running the command in my django project:-

```
$python manage.py runserver
```

then I am getting the error like:-

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
ImportError: No module named context_processors
```

here is results of

```
$ pip freeze

dj-database-url==0.4.1
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.10
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.6.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
static3==0.7.0
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I searched for many answers on stackoverflow but not getting the error.

Comment: Did you use this code somewhere? `from django.core.context_processors import csrf`?

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam in my views.py file

Comment: Can you try this? `from django.views.decorators import csrf`

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam Thanks :) it is working. can you tell me where do you know about this? i mean what is the problem in previous one?

Comment: this link may helps to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828536/django-no-module-named-context-processors-error-after-reboot

Comment: You can look at the CSRF document from 1.7, 1.8, 1.9. The `csrf` module is in different packages. Added an answer with the 1.9 link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `csrf` module is moved from `django.core.context_processors` to `django.views.decorators` in the latest release. You can refer it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/csrf/)

Answer (score 5):

`context_processors` in Django 1.10 and above has been moved from `core` to `template`.

Replace

```
django.core.context_processors
```

with

```
django.template.context_processors
```